# Fisher Test in R

Tags: r, statistical-significance, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test

Suppose we have the following data set:

```
                Men    Women    
Dieting         10      30
Non-dieting     5       60
```

If I run the Fisher exact test in R then what does `alternative = greater` (or less) imply? For example:

```
mat = matrix(c(10,5,30,60), 2,2)
fisher.test(mat, alternative="greater")
```

I get the `p-value = 0.01588` and `odds ratio =  3.943534`. Also, when I flip the rows of the contingency table like this:

```
mat = matrix(c(5,10,60,30), 2, 2)
fisher.test(mat, alternative="greater")
```

then I get the `p-value = 0.9967` and `odds ratio = 0.2535796`. But, when I run the two contingency table without the alternative argument (i.e., `fisher.test(mat)`) then I get the `p-value = 0.02063`.

1. Could you please explain the reason to me?
2. Also, what is the null hypothesis and alternative hypothesis in the above cases?
3. Can I run the fisher test on a contingency table like this:

   ```
   mat = matrix(c(5000,10000,69999,39999), 2, 2)
   ```

PS: I am not a statistician. I am trying to learn statistics so your help (answers in simple English) would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

`greater` (or `less`) refers to a one-sided test comparing a null hypothesis
that `p1=p2` to the alternative `p1>p2` (or `p1<p2`). In contrast, a two-sided
test compares the null hypotheses to the alternative that `p1` is not equal to
`p2`.

For your table the proportion of dieters that are male is 1/4 = 0.25 (10 out
of 40) in your sample. On the other hand, the proportion of non-dieters that are
male is 1/13 or (5 out of 65) equal to 0.077 in the sample.  So then the
estimate for `p1` is 0.25 and for `p2` is 0.077. Therefore it appears that
`p1>p2`.

That is why for the one-sided alternative `p1>p2` the p-value is 0.01588.
(Small p-values indicate the null hypothesis is unlikely and the alternative is
likely.)

When the alternative is `p1<p2` we see that your data indicated that the
difference is in the wrong (or unanticipated) direction.

That is why in that case the p-value is so high 0.9967.  For the two-sided
alternative the p-value should be a little higher than for the one-sided
alternative `p1>p2`. And indeed, it is with p-value equal to 0.02063.

Comment: Fantastic explanation. So, the fisher exact test actually compares probabilities between rows as opposed to columns?

Comment: @Christian: No, it doesn't matter whether its rows or columns as the fisher test checks for correlation in a contingency table. Rows and columns don't matter directly. You could also just reformulate the hypothesis: instead H0 being "people who smoke die younger" you could also be assuming H0: "people who die younger are more likely to smoke". The results of the fisher test would tell you whether any observed connection in the data supports the null-hypothesis or not, but it doesn't matter which is the independent or dependent variable and equally the choice of rows/columns doesn't matter :)