# Which ratios are being compared in fisher exact test?

Tags: statistical-significance, fishers-exact-test

I am a bit confused on which ratios are being compared in a 2x2 contingency table for a Fisher Exact test.

In this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/28235/133742), the ratios are compared between columns. However, in this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/300314/133742), the ratios are compared between rows.

Which is the correct ratio comparison for Fisher Exact? The reason I ask this is to figure out whether to use "less" or "greater" when doing a one-tailed FE test. If I'm doing a comparison between rows, then I might expect the opposite of comparison between columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fisher exact test is just as much a test of equality for the odds ratio for the row factor as for the column factor -- either way the odds ratios are the same. Indeed, rows and columns are entirely interchangeable.

Consider a 2x2 table with counts as follows:

```
                   Col. factor
                    Yes  No
      Row     Yes    a    b
     factor   No     c    d
```

Then the sample odds ratios will be equivalent to (a/c)/(b/d) for one and (a/b)/(c/d) for the other. Both simplify to ad/bc. (The same thing happens 
with the population odds; they simplify to the same quantity.)

Which way around a one tailed test is being done may depend on exactly what it says it's doing (that is, the help is usually explicit), however, it's quite straightforward to just check it -- for a 2x2 as a one-tailed test it's just a hypergeometric, so it will either be looking at this-many-or-more in a particular cell, or this-many-or-fewer -- if the program doesn't say clearly, it's not hard to figure out which it's doing by taking a specific example and seeing what p-value it gives.

Conditioning on the margins, if you're looking at $ad/bc$, lowering $a$ will necessarily increase $b$ and $c$ and lower $d$ (resulting in a smaller odds ratio of the form $ad/bc$), and raising $a$ will (correspondingly) necessarily increase $ad/bc$. A one tailed test on a 2x2 will either look at larger or smaller values for any given cell, so you can just pick a cell and see how it relates to the test.

So for example, here we double check it in R. First I make the most extreme table possible given a set of margins (row totals 8 and 8 and column totals 9 and 7), yielding the following extreme table (the top left cell cannot be made any smaller):

```
 (tab.ex=matrix(c(1,7,8,0),byrow=TRUE,nr=2))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    7
[2,]    8    0
```

Now consider the alternative "greater". If it is looking at greater values of the top left cell, this table and all tables with values of $a$ larger than this one will comprise all such tables (and we'll have p-value of exactly $1$) or it will be looking at this table plus tables with smaller values of 'a' -- which can only include this table -- and so we'll have a p-value less than $1$. So let's try it:

```
fisher.test(tab.ex,alt="greater")

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  tab.ex
p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is greater than 1
95 percent confidence interval:
   0 Inf
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
         0
```

The p-value is $1$, so it's looking at the current table plus tables with *larger* values of the top left cell when you use `greater` (this is exactly the way I would expect it to behave, but if it had done differently we'd have spotted it here and it would be no harder to use)

If you use `less` instead it gives the p-value as $0.0006993$, which is the 
[hypergeometric probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) of the specific table we gave.

```
choose(9,1)*choose(7,7)/choose(16,8)
[1] 0.0006993007
```